# Label Expression Frustration

Tags: xcode, label, expression, arcmap

I have a two label fields, [field1] & [field2] I want to display on my map. 
I want them to be on two separate lines with the bottom one in bold and in a different color and adding mg/L after the value. The bottom label also needs to all fit on one line despite it being too long, arcmap is currently separating them.  I have only written this much:

"" & [field1] & "" & vbnewline & "" &  FormatNumber(Round( [field2] , 0),0)  & " mg/L" & ""

When I add more I cant seem to get it right and lots of errors come up.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for late reply, Try to put your field2 text in these tags in label expression it will change the color and will bold your text

```
"<BOL>"& "<CLR red= '100'>" & [field2] & "</CLR>"&"</BOL>"
```

something like:

```
"" & [field1] & "" & vbnewline & "<BOL>"&"<CLR red= '100'>" & FormatNumber(Round( [field2] , 0),0) & " mg/L" & "</CLR>"&"</BOL>"
```